# Grabbing frames in a .net language

Tags: c#, .net, webcam, video-capture

I want to access cameras through DirectShow. I've found DirectShow.net, but I don't want to learn about DirectShow.

Is there a simple to use library that enumerates all cameras on a computer and then lets you access pixels of each frame as they're captured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: There's a library called [VideoInputSharp](http://code.google.com/p/videoinputsharp/). Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

There is a length [example about webcams and DirectShow](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx), over at CodeProject.com. Does this help?